# White insulating sheets inside power supply

Tags: fan, insulation

Does anyone know what this kind of sheet is called? I presume the purpose is for electrical insulation. The one in the picture is found on a fan inside a power supply.

[image]

Comment: Probably a form of elephantide or Nomex paper. Also used when winding motors or large transformers. Yes, it is used for insulation. You may find it between the bottom of the pcb and the metal case.

Answer (score 2):

In the past, vulcanized fiber (aka "[fishpaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcanized_fibre)" or "fish paper") was used for paper-like electrical insulation. A similar material is "barley paper". It's typically an greenish or grey off-white. Nowadays there are more options such as polyimide sheet (aka [Kapton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapton)) a transparent orange plastic, polyester sheet (aka Mylar) a transparent water-white plastic, and proprietary materials such as [Formex](https://www.itwformex.com/products), an opaque white polypropylene material similar to your sample.

Typical requirements on top of dielectric parameters may include UL-94 rated flame resistance, arc resistance, ease of fabrication by punching, resistance to oil, ability to absorb varnish (for motor windings), toughness (fish paper does not easily puncture) cost constraints etc. No one material is perfect for all applications.